# How to association workflow on creating of list definition

Tags: list, moss, templates, definition

I have my custom content type, and list definition. Once we create a list from this template, by default I wish to enable "Require content approval for submitted items", "Create major and minor (draft) versions", "Enable scheduling of items in this list " and approval workflow association.

My list look as :-

Also i tried added all view fields which is available in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Publishing" schema.
But still does not work.

In Sharepoint site, i created a list enable all required property and work flow association save as list temlate. After that i opened manifest file from list template and copied workflow association attribute details. 
But still does not work.

could any one guide me please?

Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [article found on MSDN about the List element in CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx). You should export your list (through say VSeWSS) and edit the List Definition to automatically enable moderation and versioning.